# Is client side validation nessesary in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation

I am writing a Django app, and am wondering if any client side validation is necessary.  Django handles all validation through forms in python on the backend.  If something validates wrong, the user is returned to the screen with all their information still there.

I can't see any reason I need to implement client side validation in Django?  Is this true?  The only reason I can think of is it would save a few hits to the server, but this seems negligible.

Comment: It could be necessary for UX, so your users get instant feedback if their form isn't correctly filled without submitting and waiting for the server to respond.

Comment: You can do the same thing with an ajax post though, and still provide a customized user experience with JavaScript that isn't replicating server-side code to do the validation.

Comment: @Brandon but what's the point of waiting for an AJAX response and wasting bandwidth if the whole validation can be done client side ?

Comment: As I stated previously, this is mostly a matter of opinion. From my perspective, waiting that 500ms for the response to go out and come back and only having to write my Django form is less of an issue than duplicating all of the validators client-side and server side. It's less maintenance, and I also don't have to worry about JS validators behaving differently in one browser versus another, although given IE 10+ that's not so much of a problem anymore.

Comment: It may be required to prevent sending malicious code injection in the post command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side validation may improve user experience (less page reloads). It may decrease number of hits to he server (but sometimes this number is increased :).  But it is not necessary.

Anyway server side validation is a must.  You can't trust data from user input.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a web application that faces the public internet client side, validation is pretty much a user expectation. You might be able to ignore this if volume is low and people are motivated to use your website.

For an company intranet site, the additional development cost may weigh against client side validation. However, if you use an available client framework (e.g. jquery or django-parsley) the additional cost for client side validation is actually fairly small and likely worth the effort in intraweb applications.

ADDED

Yes, as others had already stated client-side only validation is very bad as it is the same as no validation -- you can coerce the browser to send whatever you want back to the server.

You can do also do lots of nice things client side that you cannot server side. Sometimes these are closely related to client side validation.

E.g., limiting a comment to 500 characters. With client side code you can display a characters remaining count on screen -- with a little planning this can be integrated with the validation code.

Comment: As it has been said in other, it is ALWAYS necessary to do validations in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a matter of opinion, but I would have to say no - you don't need to implement client-side validation. Especially when you can get all of the errors from your Django form [returned as JSON](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) via a simple Ajax POST.

Django forms already do an excellent job of validating input, so why add yet more code you have to maintain in two places that does the same thing? You absolutely MUST do server-side validation anyway, so why not just do it all in one place?

Additionally, if you don't implement the same validations on the server as on the client, or worse - only do client-side validation, someone can always turn JavaScript off in the browser and possibly bypass your validation(s) or allow junk data to get into your database if you're not careful.

Comment: I feel like you've missed the point of most client-side validation: to avoid a server call. If they're your only validation you're doing it wrong anyway :p I agree about it possibly being unnecessary though.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. I'm fully aware of the extra server call. Whether or not the user experience is richer doing client-side only validation is largely a matter of individual taste. I would much rather make a call to my server where no one can see my validation code. Like anything, a proper balance to ensure a good user experience and load on the server is necessary.

Comment: I think you missed my point. That the main usage of client side validation is to do trivial validation to avoid unnecessary server calls with invalid data. And I explicitly said that client-side only is bad. In general.

Comment: Indeed :) And I'm kind of on your side in practice.

Comment: All good. No feelings hurt :)  I just don't worry about the extra server call. With so much RAM, multiple load balanced servers and a properly tuned form, view and db, the extra 300 ms is probably moot.

Comment: But it's a tool in the toolbox though. Useful for e.g. mobile and whatnot. I think we've sufficiently flagged client-only as a bad idea now too :p I also feel like your minor edit kind of made my comments superfluous

Comment: Most certainly. I've had to combine libraries like jqValidate with my server-side code to get the desired outcome, but yes, client-side only is bad, bad, bad :)

Comment: @Brandon I totally agree with you.  I mainly posted this question as confirmation that I wasn't crazy.  I agree, maintaining validation in 2 places is not a good idea.  And it saves not many hits to the server.  Django provides amazing validation already!